# Interface with symbol ppt88xx's bar code scanner using .NET CF

Tags: .net, compact-framework, hardware, barcode-scanner

I need to interface with a symbol ppt88xx's bar code scanner using .NET CF.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean on the scanner itself (from memory PPT8800 runs on Windows Mobile 2003? 2002?) you don't need to do anything to interface with it. When you scan something it sends the result of any successful read as keystrokes to the active application (just stick a textbox or something on your form, give it focus and voila). If you mean from another PDA, you can attach the PPT8800 as a Bluetooth device and, again, it acts like a virtual keyboard as far as the active application is concerned. You don't have to directly interface with the scanner at all.

Comment: Really? Have you actually worked like this? PPT8800 is Symbol made handheld device that runs Windows PPC 2003. It requires special SDK to use scanner/MSR and other hardware features.

Comment: Yes I have worked like this. You don't need any special SDK. I maintained an asset management system for a local retain chain several years ago and the field workers used the handheld component on PDTs and Axims with BT-attached scanners. The software worked indentically on both - input by the program is ultimately received as keyboard input, it doesn't know (or care) that it actually comes from a barcode scanner whether internal or otherwise.